# creating thingsboard widget on google map

Tags: thingsboard

I have created a new widget on google map using javascript and html, added a google map api(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx&callback=xxx) resource, but when i run it, gives error saying **failed to load widget resource**.

below is my code

Any help please

```js
 var map;

 function initMap() {
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(
         'map'), {
         center: {
             lat: -34.397,
             lng: 150.644
         },
         zoom: 8
     });
 }
```

```css
 #map {
     height: 100%;
 }
 /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

 html,
 body {
     height: 100%;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
```

.

Comment: Managed to solve this?